Add static text to Zoom video call screen
I would like to add static text to the top of a video call, similar to the mockup below:

I'm starting off just using Zoom's sdk sample. In the video.tsx file, the returned JSX looks like:
  return (
    <div className="viewport">
      <ShareView ref={shareViewRef} onRecieveSharingChange={setIsRecieveSharing} />
      <div
        className={classnames('video-container', {
          'video-container-in-sharing': isRecieveSharing
        })}
      >
        <canvas className="video-canvas" id="video-canvas" width="800" height="600" ref={videoRef} />
        {selfVideoLayout && mediaStream?.isRenderSelfViewWithVideoElement() && (
          <video
            id={SELF_VIDEO_ID}
            className="self-video-tag"
            playsInline
            muted
            autoPlay
            style={{
              display: 'block',
              width: `${selfVideoLayout.width}px`,
              height: `${selfVideoLayout.height}px`,
              top: `${selfVideoLayout.y}px`,
              left: `${selfVideoLayout.x}px`,
              pointerEvents: 'none'
            }}
          />
        )}

        <AvatarActionContext.Provider value={avatarActionState}>
          <ul className="avatar-list">
            {visibleParticipants.map((user, index) => {
              if (index > videoLayout.length - 1) {
                return null;
              }
              const dimension = videoLayout[index];
              const { width, height, x, y } = dimension;
              const { height: canvasHeight } = canvasDimension;
              return (
                <Avatar
                  participant={user}
                  key={user.userId}
                  isActive={activeVideo === user.userId}
                  networkQuality={networkQuality[`${user.userId}`]}
                  style={{
                    width: `${width}px`,
                    height: `${height}px`,
                    top: `${canvasHeight - y - height}px`,
                    left: `${x}px`
                  }}
                />
              );
            })}
          </ul>
          <RemoteCameraControlPanel />
        </AvatarActionContext.Provider>
      </div>
      <VideoFooter className="video-operations" sharing selfShareCanvas={shareViewRef.current?.selfShareRef} />

      {totalPage > 1 && <Pagination page={page} totalPage={totalPage} setPage={setPage} inSharing={isRecieveSharing} />}
      <ReportBtn />
    </div>
  );
};

This question on the zoom developer site says that text can be added using the code below. But I can't figure out how or where to insert it:
<View>
          <ZoomView
            style={{ width: '100%', position: 'relative', alignSelf: 'center', height: '100%', flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center' }}
            userId={user.userId}
            fullScreen
            videoAspect={VideoAspect.PanAndScan}
          />
          <Text style={{ zIndex: 100, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, color: 'white', fontSize: 20 }}>YOUR TEXT HERE</Text>
        </View>

How can I go about adding this text to the video screen?

From an answer on the zoom developers forum I was told  to add the code below somewhere near the top of the return statement, but it's  unclear where and doesn't appear to be working,
<p style={{ zIndex: 100, position: 'absolute', bottom: 0, left: 0, color: 'red', fontSize: 20 }}>YOUR TEXT HERE</p>

